# Access files on clients local network but not local machine from web server

Tags: javascript, html, r, google-chrome, shiny

I have a server that I am uploading files to every 30 minutes. That server is running a shiny server which displays that data.

The server is here

http://45.55.208.171:3838/austin/

Those files are uploaded from machines on the local network to the remote server that is running the shiny app. Is there anyway to allow the remote server to have access to those files on the users local network so it could be real time instead of 30 minute batches? The users are using chrome and are behind a fire wall and proxy server.

Comment: Where are you downloading files from SQL/Oracle Database/Other Database?

Comment: from an HTTP server on the users local network but not the users local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shiny control (`fileInput`) that will allow a user to select multiple files, and then send them to the server where they will be stored in a temp location that can then be read by the server.

Here is an example program that uses it:

```
library(shiny)
s <- shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  output$filetable <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$files)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    input$files
  })
})

u <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("File input test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("files","File data",multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("filetable")
  )
))

shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

It looks like this after selecting three example csv files:

[image]

Comment: Looking for a more automatic approach if possible. It is basically user is on machine 192.168.1.20. The files I need access to from my shiny app are at http://192.168.1.23/file.csv and http://192.168.1.24/file2.txt.

Comment: I put some work into this though and I would say I answered the question. I would suggest accepting the answer and and ask another more explicit question. Or if you found a better answer, post than post that and accept it when the delay period passes.

Comment: You are correct. This answer does meet the requirements of my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for that. :)